# Add days to date conditionally using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, conditional-formatting

I have a table that I need add days to and create a new column with that information.  The problem I am having is that there are two date calculations based on a different column.  Here is a similar table to the one I am working with:

```
Type    Name    Date
A       Abe     6/2/2021
B       Joe     6/15/2021
A       Jin     6/25/2021
A       Jen     6/1/2021
B       Pan     6/21/2021
B       Pin     6/22/2021
B       Hon     6/11/2021
A       Hen     6/23/2021
A       Bin     6/23/2021
A       Ban     6/5/2021
```

I am trying to get the table to return like this where Type A goes up by 7 days and Type B goes up by 2 business days:

```
Type    Name    Date        NewDate
A       Abe     6/2/2021    6/9/2021
B       Joe     6/15/2021   6/19/2021
A       Jin     6/25/2021   7/2/2021
A       Jen     6/1/2021    6/8/2021
B       Pan     6/21/2021   6/23/2021
B       Pin     6/22/2021   6/26/2021
B       Hon     6/11/2021   6/13/2021
A       Hen     6/23/2021   6/30/2021
A       Bin     6/23/2021   6/30/2021
A       Ban     6/5/2021    6/12/2021
```

So far I have tried these:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
df1['NewDate'] = df1.apply(df1['Date'] + timedelta(days=7) 
                 if x=='Emergency' else df1['Date'] + BDay(2) for x in df1['Type'])
```

Don't run that, either you will go in an infinite loop or it will take a very long time.

I've also run this:

```
df1['NewDate'] = [df1['Date'] + timedelta(days=7) if i=='Emergency' else df1['Date'] + BDay(2)
                 for i in df1.Type] (also tried with df1[Type] same results.
```

This puts all the rows in a single row (almost looks like how it returns on jupyter notebook with the ...)

I have also tried this:

```
df1['NewDate'] = df1['Type'].apply(lambda x: df1['Date'] + timedelta(days=7) if x=='Emergency'
                                   else df1['Date'] + BDay(2))
```

When I run that one it will go through each row on the type and apply the correct logic on the if emergency calculate by 7 days and if not calculate by business day, the problem is that every row returned is calculated on the first row of the entire table.

At this point I am a little lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.  For simplicity sakes it can be calculated at plus timedelta(7) and plus timedelta(2).  Also what would change if I had to add more conditions like say on Name column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `apply`, try:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["NewDate"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Date"]+BDay(2) if x["Type"]=="B" else x["Date"]+pd.DateOffset(days=7), axis=1)

>>> df
  Type Name       Date    NewDate
0    A  Abe 2021-06-02 2021-06-09
1    B  Joe 2021-06-15 2021-06-17
2    A  Jin 2021-06-25 2021-07-02
3    A  Jen 2021-06-01 2021-06-08
4    B  Pan 2021-06-21 2021-06-23
5    B  Pin 2021-06-22 2021-06-24
6    B  Hon 2021-06-11 2021-06-15
7    A  Hen 2021-06-23 2021-06-30
8    A  Bin 2021-06-23 2021-06-30
9    A  Ban 2021-06-05 2021-06-12
```

Alternatively, you can use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df["NewDate"] = np.where(df["Type"]=="B", df["Date"]+BDay(2), df["Date"]+pd.DateOffset(7))
```

Comment: That worked great.  So if I want to add another condition then I would just write [link]'df["NewDate"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Date"]+BDay(2) if x["Type"]=="B" & x["Name"]=="other condition" else x["Date"]+pd.DateOffset(days=7), axis=1)'  or us | for or?

Comment: Yes, use parentheses `(` and `)` as needed. `df["NewDate"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Date"]+BDay(2) if (x["Type"]=="B") & (x["Name"]=="other condition") else x["Date"]+pd.DateOffset(days=7), axis=1)`